# How does BDD capture System Interaction (Persistence, API Call, Notification etc)?

Tags: mocha.js, bdd, chai, sinon

I am a bit confused when preparing a test case with BDD.

Here is my desired requirement expressed with Gherkin Syntax.

```
Given A user is subscribed to the system
When A user try to subscribe again
Then System should send him a notification "Subscription unsuccessful"
and  Admin Portal User should view related KYC Fields as blank
```

How should **internal system interaction** be reflected in BDD ?

For example:

a) After each step, persistence is needed in MongoDB

b) A few internal API calls need to be invoked as pre-validation before the KYC API call

c) Notification needs to be send to the user after the process ends

Should **notification** be considered as **system behavior** or **business behavior**?

How should **persistence, calling an API, etc.** be reflected in BDD ?

Am I missing something?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notification being a system behavior or business behavior is largely dependent upon the system under test.

If the whole point of the scenario is to ensure a notification is sent, it is a business behavior. Basically it is all about your `Then`.

Since your scenario is asserting the notification has been sent, I would classify it as a business behavior, and your scenario is perfectly valid.

A BDD test does not necessarily need a user interface. It can involve calling APIs directly and making assertions on their results. I've even written unit tests for a single method on a class using Gherkin. It just happens to state in business terms what that method is doing. This is precisely what BDD was designed for.